# Fileobserver's onevent method fire but how can i get file before deleting any file

Tags: android, backup, restore, fileobserver

i want to copy file before deleting an image from any file manager or gallery but `FileObserver`'s `onEvent` fire but i want specifically get event only when user delete any file from `FileObserver`'s watching path

```
observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch) { // set up a file observer to watch this directory on sd card
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String fileName) {
            if (fileName == null) {
                return;
            }
            //a new file or subdirectory was created under the monitored directory

            if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event) != 0) {
                //handle deleted file
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent: DELETE");
                Log.e(TAG, "onEvent:exists(): " + new File(pathToWatch + fileName).exists());
            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
```

above code work well and also log is printing when user delete any file but at that time file not exist and returning **false** i think may be file is deleted that's why it return false but i want deleted file for backup purpose. as done by **Dumpster** please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

File Observer onEvent() method call after any file get deleted. so u are not able to copy any deleted file.

I know that this solution is not proper , but you can try this to copy deleted file.

1. create fileInputStream object for every file that you want to observe.
   make sure that object will not get garbage collect.
2. when you receive delete event in onEvent() method for any particular file, by 
   using fileinputstream of that particular file you are able to copy the file .

   ```
   public class RecoverFileObserver extends FileObserver {

     private final String TAG = RecoverFileObserver.class.getSimpleName();
     String originMd5="xyz";
     FileInputStream fileInputStream;
     String path;
     String newPath;
     private int length = 0;
     String extension;

   public RecoverFileObserver(String path) {
       super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
       this.path = path;
       Log.d(TAG, "patException:" + path);
       if (path.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) {
           extension = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));
           this.newPath = RECOVERY_DIR + "/" + MD5Utils.getMD5Str(path) + extension;
       } else {
           this.newPath = RECOVERY_DIR + "/" + MD5Utils.getMD5Str(path);
       }

       try {
           fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
           length = fileInputStream.available();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       RecoverInfo info = new RecoverInfo();
       info.originMd5 = originMd5;
       info.recoveryPath = newPath;
       recoverInfoHashMap.put(path, info);
       Log.e(TAG, "actualpath:" + path + "\n orignalmd5:" + originMd5);

   }

   @Override
   public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
       if (event == FileObserver.ACCESS) return;
       Log.v(TAG, this.path + " | " + path + " : " + event);
       switch (event) {

           case FileObserver.ACCESS:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside Access");
               break;

           case FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside AllEvents");
               break;

           case FileObserver.CLOSE_NOWRITE:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside CLOSE_NOWRITE");
               break;


           case FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside CLOSE_WRITE");
               break;

           case FileObserver.CREATE:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside CREATE");
               break;

           case FileObserver.MODIFY:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside MODIFY");
               break;

           case FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside MOVED_FROM");
               break;

           case FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside MOVED_TO");
               break;

           case FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside MOVE_SELF");
               break;

           case FileObserver.OPEN:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside OPEN");
               break;

           case FileObserver.ATTRIB:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside attrib");
               copyFile(fileInputStream, this.path, this.newPath, length, originMd5);
               break;

           case FileObserver.DELETE:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside delete");
               copyFile(fileInputStream, this.path, this.newPath, length, originMd5);
               break;

           case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside delete self");
               copyFile(fileInputStream, this.path, this.newPath, length, originMd5);
               break;

           case 32768:
               Log.d("xyzabc", "inside 32768");
               stopWatching();
               File file = new File(this.path);
               if (file.exists()) {
                   RecoverFileObserver fileObserver = new RecoverFileObserver(this.path);
                   fileObserver.startWatching();
                   myFileObserverHashMap.put(file, fileObserver);
               } else {
                   myFileObserverHashMap.remove(file);
               }
               break;
           default:
               break;
       }
   }


   @Override
   protected void finalize() {

       Log.d("xyzabc", "inside finalize");
       super.finalize();

   }
   ```

   }

This Solution Will Work For Small number of file. other wise you will get to many file open error.
I hope this will help You.

Comment: this code is not call delete event how can i call it when delete some files.

Comment: multiple file through exception when multiple fileinputstream open error like (Too much open files)